# Compare distance between each set of coordinates in Table A with all coordinates in Table B, keeping only those within X distance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis

I have two tables of Lat/Long Coordinates (Table A is ~10,000 rows and Table B is around ~100,000 rows), and am struggling to calculate pairwise distances between Table A and B.

What I'd like to do is take each individual set of coordinates from Table A, and compare it to every single set of coordinates in Table B, and tally the number of coordinates from Table B where the distance between the two is less than X miles or kilometers. And I'd like to do this for each of the 10,000 coordinates I have in Table A. I am struggling very much to even get started on this.

I have tried a few different variations of the below:

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(
  ST_GEOGPOINT(Table_A_Long, Table_A_Lat), 
  ST_GEOGPOINT(Table_B_Long, Table_B_Lat)
) AS Distance
```

But this is about as far as I can get. Any info pushing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below absolutely dummy but hopefully simple enough example for you to get high level idea

What it does it mimics your two tables and does the comparison you want leaving for each state 10 cities that have distance from state's internal point less than 100km

Note: because in below public tables lat and long presented as string  - i had to cast them into float64

```
with table1 as (
  select state_name, ST_GEOGPOINT(
      cast(internal_point_lon as float64), 
      cast(internal_point_lat as float64)
    ) table1_point
  from `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_states_area`
), table2 as (
  select name, ST_GEOGPOINT(
      cast(int_point_lon as float64), 
      cast(int_point_lat as float64)
    ) table2_point
  from `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_cities_area`
)
select state_name, 
  ARRAY_AGG(name order by ST_DISTANCE(table1_point, table2_point) limit 10) cities 
from table1
cross join table2
where ST_DISTANCE(table1_point, table2_point) < 100000
group by state_name
```

with output

[image]

Using same CTEs but preserving geodata so it can be visualized

```
select 
  state_name, 
  any_value(table1_point) as state, 
  ST_UNION_AGG(table2_point) cities
from table1
cross join table2
where ST_DISTANCE(table1_point, table2_point) < 100000
group by state_name
```

Below are few examples from result visualization

Minnesota
[image]

Georgia
[image]

Washington
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m going to give this a try